# Strange SELECT behaviour of mysql 5.7.17 on amazon aws ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

|||

Hi everyone, I face a strange problem when using SELECT in mysql 5.7.17 on ubuntu 16.04 on amazon aws EC2 server. My website and php codes work very well before I migrated from another hosting.

Database structure

```
mysql> describe map;

+--------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| uni_ac | char(8)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| uni_id | char(16) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> select * from map limit 5;
+--------+---------------+
| uni_ac | uni_id        |
+--------+---------------+
  |0A183 | LCE6A_HUMAN
 |A0A2G2 | A0A2G2_HUMAN
 |A0A2G3 | A0A2G3_HUMAN
 |A0A2G4 | A0A2G4_HUMAN
 |A0A2G5 | A0A2G5_HUMAN
+--------+---------------+
```

**The row 1 column 1 should be A0A183, I don't know why the console shows |0A183**

```
mysql> select * from map where uni_ac = 'A0A183';
+--------+--------------+
| uni_ac | uni_id       |
+--------+--------------+
 |A0A183 | LCE6A_HUMAN
+--------+--------------+
```

**Search by A0A183 it interestingly get A0A183, not |0A183**

**However, following result really troubles me**

```
mysql> select * from map where uni_id = 'LCE6A_HUMAN';
Empty set (0.03 sec)
```

**No record found for LCE6A_HUMAN, but it is in the table**

Can anybody tell me how to get the right search from mysql? Thanks in advance

Comment: Looking at your result, I suspect there is EOL or another special symbol in your second field `uni_id`. Try `select * from map where uni_id = '%LCE6A_HUMAN%';`, then save a result to a file and see it in hex mode.

Comment: Hi @MichaelO. Thanks for your advice. I think that might be the cause. I tried your sentence. No result found. I imported the data into database from windows txt file. I think I'd better redo the data import.

Comment: Yes, that might be a case, because in Windows line ending is CR+LF, while in Linux it's LF. In Linux you can use the utility `dos2unix` to convert line endings to Unix-like ones.

Comment: @MichaelO. I transformed the file into unix format and re-imported into table, now it works. Thanks very much.